# How can I create a Table of string indexs for rows and columns and boolean values for cells?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a java program that can solve the following issues:

1- It has a data structure (DS) to represent the following data where rows and columns are indexed by Strings and cells values are booleans.
[image]

So that, to access row (i), I can simply say DS["Yi"] and to access a particular cell (j) in row (i) I can say DS["Yi","Xj"]

2- The column indexs {"X1", "X2", "X3", ..., "Xn"} has to be populated from a class fields. For example consides the following class:

```
public class Test {
    private String X1;
    private String X2;
    private String X3;
    private String X4;
    private String X5;
}
```

For this class, my table's column is going to be {"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"}, and if I later update class Test to include one more field, let's say "X6", then DS has to automatically include this new field.

3- Finally, I want to save these data into a file {TXT, XML, or JSON} so that every time the code runs, it can read the values from the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do might be to have some convention whereby you can internally convert known row and column labels into numerical indices.  Then, you could just use a plain 2D boolean array.

If you can't do this, then one option would be to use a map of maps, something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> grid = new HashMap<>();
// populate first row
grid.put("Y1", new HashMap<>());
grid.get("Y1").put("X1", true);
grid.get("Y1").put("X2", true);
grid.get("Y1").put("X3", false);
// ... other columns
grid.get("Y1").put("Xn", true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A map of maps can work, however, it is expensive in terms of memory consumption as it requires for every row, I have to re-store the column headings.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with this approach.

N.B.: this code is not tested. Here I've used both int index search on array because I will assume the the list for example `"x1", "x2", "x3"` is not necessarily to be arranged(probably you can try with `Map`)

```
    public class SS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Used for indexing
        List<String> listX = Arrays.asList("x1", "x2", "x3");
        List<String> listY = Arrays.asList("y1", "y2", "y3");


        //Used to fetch boolean value which is indexed arr[x][y] with the value defined in the class YourClass
        YourClass[][] arr = new YourClass[listX.size()][listY.size()];
        int i=0;
        for (String y : listY) {
            int j=0;
            for (String x : listX) {
                //Fill the array
                arr[i][j] = new YourClass(new Random().nextInt(1), x, y);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        //To get DS["x2", "y3"]
        DS ds = new DS("x2", "y3");

        i=0;
        for (String y : listY) {
            if(ds.getY().equals(y))
            {
                int j=0;
                for (String x : listX) {
                    if(ds.getX().equals(x))
                        System.out.println(arr[i][j].toString());
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

//class to maintain index positions
class YourClass{
    int a;
    String x;
    String y;

    public YourClass(int a, String x, String y) {
        this.a = a;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "YourClass{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", x='" + x + '\'' +
                ", y='" + y + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

//class used to search the element
class DS {
    String x;
    String y;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public DS(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I guess it is diffecult to make this code dynamic as stated in point #2